# Calculating Area integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, area

I need to calculate the Integral $\int_M1$ where $M:=\{(x,y): (x^2+y^2)^2-2*x*y=0\}$
I just got no clue how to approach this problem. I just know that the integral is the area described by M which looks somewhat like an eight. Can you guys give me a hint in the right decision, because I feel lost right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$$
$$r^4=2r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta$$
$$r^2=\sin 2\theta\quad(0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}2,\pi\leq\theta\leq\frac{3\pi}2)$$
$$\int_M dxdy=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sqrt{\sin 2\theta}} rdrd\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\frac{r^2}{2}\right]_0^{\sqrt{\sin 2\theta}}d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}d\theta$$
$$=2\left[-\frac{\cos 2\theta}{4}\right]_0^{\pi/2}=1$$

Comment: Hey, shouldn´t it be $\int_0^{\sqrt{(sin(2*\phi)}}$

Comment: Oops, you're right. I just fixed.